# Was the Altair 8800 computer named after the Planet in the movie Forbidden Planet?

Tags: reference, forbidden-planet

I watched the movie [Forbidden Planet](https://falconmovies.wordpress.com/2014/05/13/forbidden-planet-1956-is-really-the-tempest-by-shakespeare/) and it’s an incredible movie, ever year that I watch it, it seems to have more relevance as it is so far ahead of it’s time, and every year we movie closer to the id being run from the subconscious and brought into reality...but that said, was the Altair 8800 computer from the famous computer club named after the planet Altair IV in this movie?

Comment: Interesting read: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Altair_8800#The_name

Comment: Agreed! That film was so well done! Even for its time!

Comment: This is not so much a question about the movie, but more about the product... isn't it off-topic or trivia?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Apparently not.

**Although the origin behind it may have been similar**

In *Forbidden Planet* the crew journey to the 4th planet of....

> "the planetary system of the great main sequence star, Altair."

Hence, Altair 4!

As for the computer, [**Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Altair_8800#The_name) has a couple of options for us as to the naming...

> One explanation of the Altair name, which editor Les Solomon later told the audience at the first Altair Computer Convention (March 1976), is that the name was inspired by Les's 12-year-old daughter, Lauren. "She said why don't you call it Altair – that's where the Enterprise is going tonight."[17] The Star Trek episode is probably "Amok Time", as this is the only one from The Original Series which takes the Enterprise crew to Altair (Six).
>
> Another explanation is that the Altair was originally going to be named the PE-8 (Popular Electronics 8-bit), but Les Solomon thought this name to be rather dull, so Les, Alexander Burawa (associate editor), and John McVeigh (technical editor) decided that: "It's a stellar event, so let's name it after a star." McVeigh suggested "Altair", the twelfth brightest star in the sky

Comment: Your research missed the internet factoid that an editor of PC Magazine confirms the second option.